# Bilinear Form - Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

I have to prove that the mapping
$f(x,y) = {\displaystyle \sum_{i=1} ^ {n} }{ \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n} }x_iy_j{f}(e_i,e_j)$

is a bilinear form, that is, inter alia, the condition:
$f(x+y,z)=f(x,z)+f(y,z)$

I have:
$f(x+y,z)=f\left({\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}}x_{i}e_{i}+{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}}y_{k}e_{k},{\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}}z_{j}e_{j}\right)=f\left({\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}}\left(x_{i}e_{i}+y_{k}e_{k}\right),{\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}}z_{j}e_{j}\right)=\ldots$

and what's next?

Help!

Comment: By definition, $f$ is bilinear: to see this explicitly, try to begin with $f(x,e_j)$ and then $f(e_i,y)$. It is sufficient to prove bilinearity!

Comment: You tried to prove linearity without using the expression of $f$... You should have $f(x+\lambda y,z)=\dots=f(x,z)+\lambda f(y,z)$ where the expression replacing the $\dots$ does not depend on $f$. And once you have done that with the left variable, you do it again with the right variable.

Answer (score 1):

First note, that 
$$ \sum_i x_i e_i + \sum_k y_k e_k \ne \sum_i \sum_k (x_i e_i + y_k e_k) $$
as the left hand side contains $n$ terms $x_1e_1$ (one for each $k$) and the right hand only one (analogously for the other terms). But, by distributivity, we have 
$$ \sum_i x_i e_i + \sum_k y_k e_k = \sum_i x_i e_i + \sum_i y_i e_i = \sum_i (x_i + y_i) e_i $$
Exploiting this, we have
\begin{align*}
  f(x+y,z) &= f \left(  \sum_i x_i e_i + \sum_i y_i e_i, \sum_j z_j e_j\right)\\
    &= f\left(\sum_i (x_i + y_i)e_i, \sum_j z_j e_j\right)\\
    &= \sum_i \sum_j (x_i + y_i)z_j f(e_i, e_j)\\
    &= \sum_i \sum_j x_i z_j f(e_i, e_j) + \sum_i \sum_j y_i z_j f(e_i, e_j)\\
    &= f(x,z) + f(y,z)
\end{align*}